# Can't filter journalctl for user service

Tags: systemd

I created the follwing service file in `~/.config/systemd/user` to backup my work data when I'm logged in at work.

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup Work Related Files

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/ping -c 1 -W 1 xxx
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync -avzuhH --progress --delete --exclude=.Trash-1000 /some/folder/ xxx@xxx:Documents/backup
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync -avzuhH --progress file xxx@xxx:Documents/backup/file
```

I can find the service with `systemctl --user list-unit-files` and I can also start the servive with `systemctl --user start backup_work.service`. For some reason though I can't see the logs for this service with `journalctl --user -u backup_work.service`. I see the logs of rsync and ping when I look normally in the journal but I can't filter to my service file.

Is there something I need to change in the service file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need **`--user-unit=`** to filter for user units, since they have different metadata attached.

```
$ SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug journalctl --user-unit=foobar
Journal filter: (((_UID=0 OR _UID=1000) AND OBJECT_SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT=foobar.service)
                 OR ((_UID=0 OR _UID=1000) AND COREDUMP_USER_UNIT=foobar.service)
                 OR (_UID=1000 AND USER_UNIT=foobar.service)
                 OR (_UID=1000 AND _SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT=foobar.service))
```

`-u` always adds filters for system units – it is independent of `--user`, which only selects which journal files to read from. (Most of the time you don't need --user.)

```
$ SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug journalctl --unit=foobar
Journal filter: ((OBJECT_SYSTEMD_UNIT=foobar.service AND _UID=0)
                 OR (UNIT=foobar.service AND _PID=1)
                 OR (COREDUMP_UNIT=foobar.service AND _UID=0 AND MESSAGE_ID=fc2e22bc6ee647b6b90729ab34a250b1)
                 OR _SYSTEMD_UNIT=foobar.service)
```